# Need to compromise on one condition to satisfy other

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm writing a XSLT to convert my XML to HTML and below is my XML.

```
<para>
  <page num="9"/><phrase>1.017</phrase><content-style font-style="bold">Context .</content-style> content
  <para1>Hello</para1>
  <para1>There</para1>
</para>
```

And below is my XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>
        <div>
            <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>para</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para1">
    <span>
    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>para</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page[not(preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::text()) or normalize-space()])]"/>

<xsl:template match="page" mode="first">
    <xsl:variable name="pgn">
        <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
        <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pgn"/>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <a name="{concat('pg_',$pgn)}"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="content-style">        
    <span class="font-style-{./@font-style}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>            
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

Here I've the below cases.

1. I've a `page` to determine the page number.
2. I've two inner `para1` in 2 lines and there is no space (Just a line break).

**Problem:**

1. When I run my XSLT as it is I'm able to get a space in the output (Between the 2 `para1` divided with a line break), but I'm unable to retain the `page`
2. When I add a `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`, I'm able to retain the `page`(as required), but here the inner `para1` is printed without a space in between.

Below are my output screenshots.

**With strip-space**

[image]

**Without strip-space**

[image]

Here is a working demo. http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuD/2. please remove `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to see my problem.

This is very confusing.

Please let me know how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: If you want a space, why don't insert it explicitly where you need it (and keep the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` instruction?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, thanks for that quick tip, But this is only a single tag for demonstration, I've multiple such inner tags. That's why I don't want to do this manually :(

Comment: Perhaps you could do this globally, by appending a space to every text node. I would prefer a more selective solution, but I cannot be more specific without a specific example.

Comment: Have you tried changing `./node()` to `*` on line 21? (http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuD/3)

Comment: @DanielHaley, thanks for that, but the O/P remains the same.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, here is an updated question with additional data, hope this suffices the requirement. Also Expected O/P is added there itself. http://xsltransform.net/6rewNxF/2

Comment: You could add `xsl:preserve-space` with elements that you don't want to strip space from. Most likely elements with mixed content (both text and element children). Something like `<xsl:preserve-space elements="text leg-ref"/>` (http://xsltransform.net/6rewNxF/3)

Comment: Hi @DanielHaley, thanks for that quick tip, I tried the other way like, `<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="page"/>`, but this doesn't seem working :(